Flutter Null check operator used on a null value, Widget Builder
This my app_page.dart
import 'package:get/get.dart';import 'package:my_grocery/route/app_route.dart';import 'package:my_grocery/view/dashboard/dashboard_binding.dart';import 'package:my_grocery/view/dashboard/dashboard_screen.dart';

class AppPage {static var list = [GetPage(name: AppRoute.dashboard,page: () => const DashboardScreen(),binding: DashboardBinding())];}`

And this is my dashboard_screen.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';import 'package:flutter_snake_navigationbar/flutter_snake_navigationbar.dart';import 'package:get/get.dart';import 'package:my_grocery/controller/dashboard_controller.dart';

class DashboardScreen extends StatelessWidget {const DashboardScreen({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GetBuilder<DashboardController>(
    builder: (controller) => Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: controller.tabIndex,
          children: [
            Container(),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
            )

          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border(
                top: BorderSide(
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                    width: 0.7
                )
            )
        ),
        child: SnakeNavigationBar.color(
          behaviour: SnakeBarBehaviour.floating,
          snakeShape: SnakeShape.circle,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
          unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 11),
          snakeViewColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          unselectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
          currentIndex: controller.tabIndex,
          onTap: (val){
            controller.updateIndex(val);
          },
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.category), label: 'Category'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), label: 'Menu'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), label: 'Account')
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
 }
} 

I just follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upg71WsUOfs&list=PLVpp0SvtYtdfMvoSB1NwHq3J0MFHSz5FQ&index=2
and im stuck when get it done
Can someone help me I,m not use the '!' but it say i used null checker please help Thank You.
